# How to display background color linearly after scrolling on menu section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to display linearly background color after scroll on menu. In the current section there is no background color but after scrolling a background color should be displayed. How can I achieve this?

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".entry_section").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".scroll-menu").addClass("scroll-menu-padding");
        $(".scroll-menu").addClass("fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg");
    
     
    } else {
        $(".scroll-menu").removeClass("scroll-menu-padding");
         $(".scroll-menu").removeClass("fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg");
     
    }
});
```

```css
body{
 height: 900px;
}
.entry_section
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.fixed-entry-field
{
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

.fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg
{
    background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry_section scroll-menu" >
<div class="fixed-entry-field">
<p>linear background color after scrolling</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: what is linear background color?

Comment: I have to display background color linearly

Comment: By running your snippet I see that the background-color is already displayed when we scroll, so what's exactly your goal? The background color should cover the whole body instead of that small section, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for reply. You can check in snippet.If  you scroll down than background color  will display but i have to display linearly.

Comment: Do you want the background to fade linearly as you scroll? Do you want the color to slide in linearly as you scroll? "display background color linearly" just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Right. I am talking about that background color should be display linearly.now that showing directly

Comment: linearly(top to bottom ) ?? with transition??

Comment: right what? I said two possibilities. please don't say display linearly again.

Comment: @NarendraVerma [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/cb0stz3r/2/ ] check this one. are you looking like this ??

Comment: Yes. Mr.Mostafa, I need this

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird as you're attributting `height: 0;` on your fixed element, that way when you apply `padding: 25px` it pushes the content down getting that unlinear effect you've mentioned.

By simply removing that constrain you get the desired effect on your menu upon scrolling.

Check this updated snippet for full behaviour.

PS: If you want the height to remain the same, just remove that padding of 20px on your `.fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg` class that it will do the trick.

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".entry_section").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".scroll-menu").addClass("scroll-menu-padding");
        $(".scroll-menu").addClass("fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg");
    
     
    } else {
        $(".scroll-menu").removeClass("scroll-menu-padding");
         $(".scroll-menu").removeClass("fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg");
     
    }
});
```

```css
body{
 height: 900px;
}
.entry_section
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.fixed-entry-field
{
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

.fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg
{
    background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px 0;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry_section scroll-menu" >
<div class="fixed-entry-field">
<p>linear background color after scrolling</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the css part .fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg here I used transition for the effect and linear-gradient for the color [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/cb0stz3r/2/). For more details read this  [Linear Gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) & for [Transition Effect](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

```js
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".entry_section").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".scroll-menu").addClass("scroll-menu-padding");
        $(".scroll-menu").addClass("fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg");
    
     
    } else {
        $(".scroll-menu").removeClass("scroll-menu-padding");
         $(".scroll-menu").removeClass("fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg");
     
    }
});
```

```css
body{
 height: 900px;
}
.entry_section
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.fixed-entry-field
{
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

.fixed-entry-field-scroll-bg
{
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: red;
  /* Standard syntax */
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #bbb);
  /* For Safari this the part  */
  -webkit-transition: width 0.7s, height 0.8s; 
  transition: width 0.7s, height 0.8s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  padding: 25px 0;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="entry_section scroll-menu" >
<div class="fixed-entry-field">
<p>linear background color after scrolling</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help Mr.Mostafa. I need one more help.

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});

Comment: Above code is if page is refresh scroll will display at bottom with animate.But i don't need animate, scroll bar should be display fixed at bottom.

Comment: @NarendraVerma don't understand. Please explain a bit more